How to web scrape a page that has collapsible fields using Selenium?
There is this website -  https://www.flashscore.com/  and I'm looking to extract fixture data, including the competition name, team names, and dates. While I've already developed a scraping solution, I'm encountering an issue with collapsible competitions.
To illustrate, consider the image below: The Andorra: Andorra Cup section features a trigger button that must be activated before scraping. Therefore, I aim to automate the process of clicking on all of these buttons to expand the fields for scraping.
Andorra
url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/'  # Replace this with the URL of the website

# Open the website
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the calendar date picker button to be clickable
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'calendar__datepicker')))
button_text = button.text.strip()

all_data = []
for _ in range(1):  # Click the "Next day" button three times
    
    # next_day_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'calendar__navigation--tomorrow')
    
    
    next_day_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'calendar__navigation--tomorrow')))
    
    # Dismiss the cookie banner if it appears
    try:
        cookie_banner = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-banner-sdk')))
        cookie_banner.click()  # Click to dismiss the cookie banner if found
    except:
        pass  # If the cookie banner doesn't appear or can't be dismissed
    
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_day_button)
   
    # next_day_button.click()
    
    # Wait for the loading overlay to disappear after clicking
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'loadingOverlay')))
    
    
    
    next_day_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'calendar__navigation--tomorrow')))
    
    # Dismiss the cookie banner if it appears
    try:
        cookie_banner = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-banner-sdk')))
        cookie_banner.click()  # Click to dismiss the cookie banner if found
    except:
        pass  # If the cookie banner doesn't appear or can't be dismissed
    
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_day_button)
   
    # next_day_button.click()
    
    # Wait for the loading overlay to disappear after clicking
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'loadingOverlay')))

    # Get the date for each day
    date_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'calendar__datepicker')
    date = date_element.text.strip()
    print("Date:", date)

    # Get the page source after loading the subsequent days
    html_content = driver.page_source

    # Use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

    # Find all event containers
    event_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_='event__match')
    

    data = []

    for event in event_containers:
        #print(event.prettify())
        # Extract event type
        event_type = event.find_previous('div', class_='event__title')
        
       ** button_check = event.find_previous('div', class_='wclIcon__leagueShowMoreCont')
        
        trigger_element = button_check.find(class_='_trigger_9ionf_42')
       
    
        
        if trigger_element:
            trigger_element['data-state'] = 'open'**
            
        print(button_check.prettify())
        
        
        event_type_text = event_type.find(class_='event__titleInfo').get_text(strip=True)
        # print("Country:", event_type_text)
        
        # Extract event name
        event_name = event_type.find(class_='event__titleBox').get_text(strip=True)
        # print("Event Name:", event_name)
        
        # Extract event time
        event_time_elem = event.find(class_='event__time')
        event_time = event_time_elem.get_text(strip=True) if event_time_elem else 'No time available'
        # print("Event Time:", event_time)
        
        # Extract teams
        away_team = event.find(class_='event__participant--away').get_text(strip=True)
        home_team = event.find(class_='event__participant--home').get_text(strip=True)
        
        data.append({
            'Date': date,
            'Country': event_type_text,
            'Event Name': event_name,
            'Event Time': event_time,
            'Home Team': home_team,
            'Away Team': away_team
        })
        

        all_data.extend(data)
# print(all_data)
        

 #Create a DataFrame using pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

I tried to find the button with class- 'wclIcon__leagueShowMoreCont' and change he data-state to open but it doesn't work.
updated code-

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'onetrust-banner-sdk')))

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


# elements = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'display matches')]")))
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'display matches')]")))

# Click on each of the collapsible element and expand it
for element in elements:
    
    element.click()



"Therefore, I aim to automate the process of clicking on all of these buttons to expand the fields for scraping"
I did not see the entire code you have shared, it's too long. Answering specific to your above statement regarding clicking the collapsible elements.
You can use this XPath //span[contains(text(),'display matches')] to locate all the desired collapsible elements. Once all elements are located, put the elements in a loop and click each one of them. Refer the code below which does exactly what I just said.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Click on I Accept cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

# Store all collapsible elements into a variable
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'display matches')]")))

# Click on each of the collapsible element and expand it
for element in elements:
    element.click()

Once all elements are expanded, you can just scrape it.

Thank you. I am getting an error message - ---> 6 elements = WebDriverWait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'display matches')]")))
8 # Click on each of the collapsible element and expand it
9 for element in elements:
TypeError: WebDriverWait.until() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'

I think you have not instantiated WebDriverWait, check if you have created wait object? This code - wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

I have done that

This is the new error message-
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'find_elements'

These are syntax and import related code issues. You should figure this out in your code. Anyway, share your updated code again in the question in the form of text, let me check.

I have added the updated code and I have got different issues- ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (672, 592). Other element would receive the click: <div id="onetrust-banner-sdk" class="otFlat ot-iab-2 bottom vertical-align-content ot-buttons-fw" tabindex="0" role="region" aria-label="Cookie banner"

Hey, anything on this?
